# Install Error PHP5-Curl Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, ubuntu-server, php-curl

PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6 (cli) (built: Apr 17 2015 15:47:51)

Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04

```
apt-get install php5-curl

Read package lists ... Done
Dependency tree is established.
Status information is read in .... Done
Try "apt-get -f install" to correct this:
The following packages have unfulfilled dependencies:
  libfontconfig1: Depends on: fontconfig-config (= 2.11.0-0ubuntu4.2) but 2.11.94-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
  php5-curl: Depends on: libcurl3 (> = 7.18.0) should not be installed
              Depends on: phpapi-20121212
              Depends on: php5-common (= 5.5.9 + dfsg-1ubuntu4.22) but 5.6.4 + dfsg-4ubuntu6 should be installed
E: Unfulfilled dependencies. Try "apt-get -f install" without specifying a package (or specify a solution).
```

Output from "sudo apt-get install software-properties-common":

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Probieren Sie »apt-get -f install«, um dies zu korrigieren:
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 libfontconfig1 : Hängt ab von: fontconfig-config (= 2.11.0-0ubuntu4.2) aber 2.11.94-0ubuntu2 soll installiert werden
 software-properties-common : Hängt ab von: python-apt-common (>= 0.9) soll aber nicht installiert werden
                              Hängt ab von: python3-dbus soll aber nicht installiert werden
                              Hängt ab von: python3-software-properties (= 0.92.37.8) soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie »apt-get -f install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).
```

Comment: Try using 'sudo apt-get install php5-curl'. And then restart apache server 'sudo service apache2 restart'.

Comment: You need to update the packages on which php5-curl depends.

Comment: @neodan can you tell me the command?

Answer (score 0):

You can install php5-curl as follows

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

If you are not succeed you may need to uninstall old php packages first.

```
sudo apt-get remove php5 php5-common php5-mysql php5-xmlrpc php5-cgi php5-curl php5-gd php5-cli php5-fpm php-apc php-pear php5-dev php5-imap php5-mcrypt
```

Comment: Run this command - sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-software-properties not work :/

Comment: @HosonoDesign - 'sudo apt-get install software-properties-common' will work definitely. And then install packages.

Comment: output is too long for the comment. can i send you a pn?